# Why does isNaN() returns inconsistent results for strings?

Tags: javascript

Please consider following examples.

In this case isNaN returns false

```
> isNaN('014e02768282049601000001')
< false
```

But here it returns true

```
> isNaN('014e0276861d077601000001')
< true
```

What is the difference between these two strings with hex-numbers?

What is reliable way in JS to detect numbers and non-numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: in first string valid number in exponential form, in second not valid

Comment: @Grundy, because of the `d` in the middle?

Comment: yep, if you want parse it to number - use `parseInt` for example

Comment: @Grundy
parseFloat() returns Infinity for both, parseInt() returns 14 for both

`> parseFloat('014e02768282049601000001')
Infinity

> parseFloat('014e0276861d077601000001')
Infinity

> parseInt('014e02768282049601000001')
14

> parseInt('014e0276861d077601000001')
14

`

Comment: because you do it wrong :-D

Comment: try `parseInt('014e0276861d077601000001',16)` - second argument is radix [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @Grundy, I receive it as a string ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80856/discussion-between-grundy-and-paker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`014e02768282049601000001` is a valid number written in an exponential form, like: `5e2` (==500 = 5 * 10²). The second one contains a letter `d`, which has no particular meaning, thus is not a number.

You can declare the exponential form in JavaScript and many other languages literally:

`var b = 3e-20;`

The characters `e`, `-`, `+` and `.` belong to the set of characters used when defining numbers (of course, if used properly). Other characters don't.

Answer (score 2):

Those two strings are not interpreted as hex numbers. Hex numbers must start with `0x`.

But the first one has the form of a valid number literal:

```
2e3
```

is the same as

```
2 * Math.pow(10,3);
```

The second one is invalid because it contains `d`.